# What does it mean to "get variable" in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Several times I saw the following statement:

> tf.get_variable gets from the graph an existing variable

What exactly does it mean? If a variable already exists, why can't I reuse it (or "get it") by calling its name. For example, I have a variable `x`, so I just use this variable everywhere I need it. Why should I use `get_variable` to "get" it (whatever it means)?

Comment: Have you used `logging` module? For example, I have a logger `logger`, so I just use this variable everywhere I need it. But I can also use `logging.getLogger(logger_name)` to get `logger` across multiple name scopes.

Comment: If you haven't already, take a look at the [TensorFlow guide on variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables). `get_variable` can create or reuse variables depending on the context and it is useful (along with `variable_scope`) to write functions that create subgraphs with predictable variable names (see the "Sharing variables" section in the guide).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If a variable already exists, why can't I reuse it (or "get it") by calling its name.

You can and that's usually done when the whole model is in one file. However, the big model is likely to be split into different source files and libraries. In this case, `tf.get_variable` is simply [convenient](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables): "`tf.get_variable` also allows you to reuse a previously created variable of the same name, making it easy to define models which reuse layers".

Out-of-the-box layers and functions in tensorflow often define their variables with `tf.get_variable`, for example [`tf.contrib.crf.crf_log_likelihood`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/crf/crf_log_likelihood) ([source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/contrib/crf/python/ops/crf.py#L151)), which allows the client to pass a `transitions` matrix even if `crf_log_likelihood` invocation is in another module or even in third-party code.

The possibility of sharing is another use-case, as already suggested in the comments, so writing `tf.get_variable` deep within a layer is a step towards better compositionality.