# What is get_variable in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I am learning tensorflow and i found a code online in which they used get_variable() in it. What is this function?
Like this line of code:

```
W1 = tf.get_variable("W1", [25, 122], initializer = 
                    tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
```

And also what this initializer is doing in it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Variable and get\_variable in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098546/difference-between-variable-and-get-variable-in-tensorflow)

Comment: Also see [the programmer's guide about variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables) in the TensorFlow docs.

Comment: One more related question: [What does it mean to “get variable” in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46705354/712995)